# Is it possible to set up a 'wildcard' subdomain in IIS so that any subdomain can be used and routed by the application?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, routing

My first question on ServerFault..be gentle :)

Is it possible to set up a 'wildcard' subdomain in IIS (assume version 7 or later) so that any subdomain can be used and routed by the application?  For example, if my domain was 'example.com', then I would like to have essentially any subdomain, for example, all of the below would be routed:

football.example.com
baseball.example.com
lacrosse.example.com

This would mean that no additional configuration on the web server would be necessary for additional subdomains, and that the above three URLs would route to the same place (I will have logic in my application to display pages correctly based on the subdomain).

I know that this is essentially equivalent to www.example.com/football, www.example.com/baseball, etc.  This is my fallback if I cannot find a solution for the above.

EDIT:  I know that this is doable in DNS by setting additional records - I am trying to solve this without constantly having to add these records.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault. - A couple of initial observations regarding your scenario.

- this is a domain - example.com
- this is a host - www.example.com
- this is a subdomain - info.example.com
- this is a host on a sub domain - www.info.example.com
- this is a url example.com/info

this first 4 examples need to be resolved to an IP address (DNS) and the URL is handled by the server(HTTP), domains,subdomain, hosts, aliases and such are all terminology of the domain name server protocol and url is from the http protocol. So you assumption is correct you need some type of DNS record (first a subdomain, you can have this point to your server IP address if you want to, and then aliases or cname records that are an aliases of you default websites hostname).
I won't go on about website bindings or virtual hosts, but using the examples above you can see what you can (and must) achieve with DNS, and the alternative you mentioned.